# Deleting virtual class without virtual destructor

Tags: c++

In the following code, will small `c` will leak ?

I believe that not, as it is not dynamically allocated, the struct will be deleted entirely

From my peers I got the following answers :

1. It is undefined behavior
2. It will leak
3. It wont leak

Here is the code :

```
class A 
{
    public:
    void printA() { cout << "A" << endl;}
    virtual void printB() { cout << "B" << endl;}
    int a;
};

class C : public A
{
    public :
    void printA() { cout << "C" << endl;}
    void printB() { cout << "D" << endl;}
    int c;
};

int main() 
{
    A* bla = new C();
    bla->printA();
    bla->printB();
    delete bla;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "as it is not dynamically allocated", `bla` is dynamically allocated, and thats all that matters, because `c` is member of it

Comment: _"...If expression evaluates to a pointer to a base class subobject of the object that was allocated with new, the destructor of the base class must be virtual, otherwise the behavior is undefined...."_ [delete expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/delete)

Comment: [Posssible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25220229/in-c-inheritance-derived-class-destructor-not-called-when-pointer-object-to-b)

Comment: its not only objects allocated by `new` whose memory has to be managed. Its just easily overlooked and/or ignored, that most memory is managed automatically in C++

Comment: There's no such thing as a "virtual class". The issue here is simply about a base class without a virtual destructor.